# Kafka Streams batch processing

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have Spring-based application and I want to run Kafka Streams jobs once per week in Monday to process all the data from previous week. Is it possible to configure Spring Kafka Streams to process data as batch?

Comment: this may help you : https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-batch-listener-example/

Comment: thank you very much @Valath.
This approach is good for kafka listener but I'm using kafka streams.

Comment: I think its hard to achieve your use case with streams or even with my comment above. May be you can control the docker start and stop via cron job to schedule your stream processing app to pick all the events currently in queue on a particular day of week. Explore KsqlDB also.